# Are Io multiplexers generally bidirectional?

Tags: multiplexer

I'm looking for an IC to multiplex i2c and 1-wire sensors (SDA & IO).
Are these ICs generally bidirectional?
For instance, I found this, but the datasheet talks about input and output in a way that makes me think it is not bidirectional... But there is no category on digikey to filter one or the other either.
The logic sketch of this example seems exactly like what I'm looking for. A single signal to control which of two MCU-pins that's connected to my external sensor pin. But I need it to go both ways...

If the answer is "sometimes", what are terminology to look for to determine if the IC is bidirectional?

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G157.pdf
[image: logic]

Comment: bidirectional multiplexer or analog(ue) multiplexer are the terms I'd use.

Comment: Not digital muxes because they read and regenerate the signal with logoc gates, not pass it through with transistors.

Comment: "Analog switch" seems to be what I am looking for, not a "multiplexer". From the minor additional research I've had time to do I think the answer to my original question is "no, they are generally not bidirectional".